# How to prove these Hausdorff sentences?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, \tau)$ a topological space.

**a)** If $(X, \tau)$ is Hausdorff and $x \in X$, then $\{x\}$ is closed.

**b)** In a Hausdorff space, every finite subset is closed.

**c)** If every finite subset is closed, then $(X, \tau)$ is Hausdorff.

And I have to prove that **a** and **b** are true and **c** is false. How can I prove them?

Comment: c. requires an example. That a implies b is clear, as closed sets are preserved by finite unions.  a. is clear because no point $ y \neq x$ is in the closure of $\{x\}$, because of the Hausdorffness.

Comment: Refer to J.R.Munkres, Topology. https://www.amazon.com/Topology-2nd-James-Munkres/dp/0131816292

Comment: Do you mean that Hausdorff uttered these sentences? Welcome to MSE! Usually you are expected to (a) post a single question (post separate questions if you have more than one), (b) clearly show that you attempted to answer the question on your own, and what progress you have made, and what are your difficulties in getting an answer (so other could get an idea what specific help you need).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For (a), show that the complement of $\{x\}$ is closed. Indeed, given any $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$ there are open and disjoint $V_y$ and $U_y$ with $x\in V_y$ and $y\in U_y$. Then $X\setminus\{x\}=\cup\{U_y:y\in X\setminus\{x\}\}$, which is open, as the union of open sets.

For (b) use (as pointed out in the first comment) that the union of finitely many closed sets is closed. That is, $F=\{x_1,...,x_n\}=\{x_1\}\cup...\cup\{x_n\}$, and each $\{x_j\}$ is closed.

For (c), are you familiar with the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) on any infinite set? It is the standard example in this context.